# Bukkit Commands In Command Blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I'm running a Bukkit server, on which I am trying to use Command Blocks to run commands. In one Command Block, I have tried to use `save-all`, but when activated, nothing happens

The command `sudo` works, as i tried `/sudo @a gc`

But the sudo command doesn't work with `save-all` either.

Comment: Where you get the sudo command? There no such command in a original server or bukkit server...

Comment: It's a part of the essentials plugin for bukkit servers

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the sudo command is `/<command> <player> <command [args]>` and its description is *Make another user perform a command*. With the command `/sudo @a gc` you force every player to execute `/gc`. Means everyone see the server usage information.

If you typed `/sudo @a save-all` in the commandblock, be happy that it dosen't work because that could be ending in a server crash. (Everybody on the server is forced to execute the command `/save-all`, what needs much hardware usage)

What I think that you missleading it with the sudo command from linux where the command is executed as root.

The problem why you can not execute the command `/save-all` in a commandblock is because it is disabled from the server itself for security reasons.

In the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Unusable_commands) you find that information:

> These commands are likely disabled due to limited use in command
> blocks and the potential for severe, unintended consequences on
> servers.

That counts for the commands:

> ban, ban-ip, deop, kick, op, pardon, pardon-ip, save-all, save-off,
> save-on, stop, whitelist add/remove/on/off/reload, debug, publish

If you really need that command, the only possibility is to use a command of a other plugin and not the original command `/save-all`.

But make sure that it is **executed only once**! Keep in mind that griefer could use it to crash the server by expensive hardware usage if they spam the button!